# How to handle nested json duplicate entries and save it in new row in csv?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert API response into a csv file.

What issue I am facing??

> Look at the `files` and `descriptions` fields in the below attached json.

> In the API response these array can have any no of entries as you can see in example json.

What I want to achieve?

> I want a csv file which has columns as follow.

> `id`, `img1`, `img2`, ...(all images)..., `Market Description`, `Associated Comments`, ...(all descriptions)...

*here img1, img2,.. etc is in `files`.`links`.`url`*

and

*for descriptions... The value of `discriptions`.`type` should be the column name. and `discriptions`.`discription` should be the value in the respective column.*

I tried to use `json_normalize` but, as these `files` and `descriptions` arrays are of random lengths I am completely clueless that how I can handle that.

Please help me out with this. Thanks for giving your valuable time. Any kind of help or guidance is valuable for me.

Also, let me know If you guys have any other approaches or anything which can help me out.

**API Response::**

````
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "35776",
            "type": "ProductData",
            "files": [
                {
                    "id": "2894907",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Primary",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://d32vzsop7y1h3k.cloudfront.net/cc3a35729a75a8510c4a0b14a7fc6fd4.JPG",
                            "height": "1070.00",
                            "width": "800.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "6196485",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Primary",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://d32vzsop7y1h3k.cloudfront.net/b8c7fa80b5e6fc9d35e2a8c8ee59e9ef.JPG",
                            "height": "570.00",
                            "width": "800.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "7079630",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Primary",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://d32vzsop7y1h3k.cloudfront.net/7c39c695853f4a51ff1fe957cc4b2103.JPG",
                            "height": "533.00",
                            "width": "800.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "13400593",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Primary",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://d32vzsop7y1h3k.cloudfront.net/95f42ba54e4106298efb5e84955e91a9.JPG",
                            "height": "800.00",
                            "width": "800.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "23536454",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Photo - Primary",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://d32vzsop7y1h3k.cloudfront.net/9ef4515f90311a25e69f87111bee03f9.JPG",
                            "height": "800.00",
                            "width": "800.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "7079629",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "PNG",
                    "media_content": "Logo Image",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://d32vzsop7y1h3k.cloudfront.net/b2e60a9f192a7032e8b87b966c826187.PNG",
                            "height": "390.00",
                            "width": "800.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "13400592",
                    "type": "Image",
                    "file_extension": "JPG",
                    "media_content": "Logo Image",
                    "generic": true,
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://d32vzsop7y1h3k.cloudfront.net/99b17aa8393a06019fea7b4bb1b58727.JPG",
                            "height": "417.00",
                            "width": "800.00",
                            "size": "L"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "descriptions": [
                {
                    "type": "Market Description",
                    "description": "All EBC rotors are made from OE spec grey cast iron, exactly as used on new car production and as many as we have tools for are BRITISH MADE wholly in our own UK foundry. Currently EVERY SINGLE ROTOR sold in Europe and the UK is BRITISH MADE and a majority of the designs specific to the USA are also BRITISH made.The British foundry is constantly expanding its in house tooled range but EBC like every brake manufacturer ....does need occasionally to buy some rotors in from approved sources to complete ranges in overseas markets. None of our competitors will ever tell you where their rotors come from and we at EBC are as disappointed as the rest of the world that cost pressure means there is not ONE foundry left in the USA to supply such parts, other brake brands when asked about origin will just sidestep the question. When we do buy rotors in, they are specified, sampled, tested for element analysis, grain structure, tensile strength, hardness and optimum ductility and tested 100 piece by piece to be perfect for runout on this in house machine."
                },
                {
                    "type": "Associated Comments",
                    "description": "DO NOT FIT UPGRADE PADS TO REAR OF VEHICLE UNLESS SAME UPGRADE FITTED TO FRONT, The ?Thermic Black coating? does NOT need to be removed before install. Do NOT use brake cleaner or any other method to remove Thermic Black coating from discs rotors. The Thermic black coating will be removed in the pad swept area by the brake pads with in the first 10 to 20 stops made after installation on the vehicle.The ?Thermic Black coating? is an anti corrosion coating for long resistance against rust. Attempting to remove Thermic Black Coating with brake cleaner or any other method is NOT covered under EBC warranty"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Associated Comments",
                    "description": "DO NOT FIT UPGRADE PADS TO REAR OF VEHICLE UNLESS SAME UPGRADE FITTED TO FRONT, The Thermic Black coating? does NOT need to be removed before install. Do NOT use brake cleaner or any other method to remove Thermic Black coating from discs rotors. The Thermic black coating will be removed in the pad swept area by the brake pads with in the first 10 to 20 stops made after installation on the vehicle.The Thermic Black coating? is an anti corrosion coating for long resistance against rust. Attempting to remove Thermic Black Coating with brake cleaner or any other method is NOT covered under EBC warranty"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Product Description - Extended",
                    "description": "EBC's GD sport rotors features wide aperture slots for cooling to reduce temperatures preventing brake fade. Dimple drilling avoids stress cracks with Thermic black finish with a sleek look whilst preventing corrosion."
                },
                {
                    "type": "Market Description",
                    "description": "Feature wider slots and blind drilled dimples to avoid cracks, these degas pads and remove dirt dust and debris from braking area"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Product Description - Extended",
                    "description": "EBC 3GD Series Sport Slotted Rotors; Rear; 11.1 in. Dia.; Set of Two;"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Product Description - Short",
                    "description": "EBC 09-14 Acura TSX 2.4 GD Sport Rear Rotors"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2004 thru 2005 HONDA Accord Sedan 3.0 Hybrid"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2006 thru 2007 HONDA Accord Sedan 3.0 Hybrid"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2013 thru 2016 HONDA Accord Sedan 2.0 hybrid"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Sedan 3.5 Touring"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Coupe 3.5 Touring"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Sedan 2.0 hybrid"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Product Description - Long",
                    "description": "GD Rotors REAR Disc Brake Rotor FMSI D537"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2007 thru 2012 HONDA Accord Sedan 2.4 EX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2008 thru 2012 HONDA Accord Sedan 2.4 LX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2013 thru 2015 HONDA Accord Sedan 2.4 LX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2013 thru 2015 HONDA Accord Sedan 2.4 EX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Sedan 2.4 Sport"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2008 thru 2012 HONDA Accord Coupe 2.4 EX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2008 thru 2012 HONDA Accord Coupe 2.4 LX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2013 thru 2015 HONDA Accord Coupe 2.4 LX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2013 thru 2015 HONDA Accord Coupe 2.4 EX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Coupe 2.4 LX-S"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Coupe 3.5 EX-L"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Sedan 2.4 EX-L"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Coupe 2.4 EX-L"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Sedan 3.5 EX-L"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Coupe 2.4 EX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Sedan 2.4 EX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 and up HONDA Accord Sedan 2.4 LX"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2008 thru 2012 HONDA Accord Sedan 3.5"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2013 thru 2015 HONDA Accord Sedan 3.5"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2008 thru 2012 HONDA Accord Coupe 3.5"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2013 thru 2015 HONDA Accord Coupe 3.5"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Product Description - Invoice",
                    "description": "GD7440 REAR GD Pattern Rotors"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2009 thru 2014 ACURA TSX 2.4"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2010 thru 2014 ACURA TSX 3.5"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2015 and up HONDA HR-V 1.8"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2017 and up ACURA ILX 2.4"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Product Description - Long",
                    "description": "EBC GD SPORT ROTOR KIT"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Product Description - Short",
                    "description": "EBC Brakes GD Sport"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Application Summary",
                    "description": "2016 ACURA ILX 2.4"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Product Description - Short",
                    "description": "GD Pattern Rotors"
                },
                {
                    "type": "AAIA Part Type Description",
                    "description": "Disc Brake Rotor"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Product Description - Long",
                    "description": "EBC GD ROTOR KIT"
                }
            ],
            "relationships": {
                "vehicle_fitments": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": "/v1/items/fitment/35776"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

With the json file you provided, here is one way to do it:

```py
df = pd.read_json("file.json")

# Get urls
images = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df["files"][0])["links"].apply(lambda x: x[0]["url"])
# Reshape urls as 'horizontal' dataframe
images = pd.DataFrame(images).T.reset_index(drop=True)
# Renames columns
images.columns = [f"img{i}" for i in range(images.shape[1])]

# Get descriptions as 'horizontal' dataframe
descriptions = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df["descriptions"][0]).T.reset_index(drop=True)
# Grab the first row for the header
new_header = descriptions.iloc[0]
# Take the data less the header row
descriptions = descriptions[1:]
# Set the header row as the df header and clean index
descriptions.columns = new_header
descriptions = descriptions.reset_index(drop=True)

# Final dataframe
df = pd.concat([images, descriptions], axis=1)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output
             img0            img1            img2            img3  \
0  https://d32...  https://d32...  https://d32...  https://d32...   

             img4  ... Product Description - Short Application Summary  \
0  https://d32...  ...  EBC Brakes ...              2016 ACURA ...       

  Product Description - Short AAIA Part Type Description  \
0  GD Pattern ...              Disc Brake ...

  Product Description - Long  
0  EBC GD ROTO...

[1 rows x 53 columns]
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is...

I am triggering an API for a list of IDs, each response has a different length of Images and Description array,

For example: 
consider there is 5 ids.. 123, 289, 232, 569, 962

response of 123 contains --> 2 imgs and 5 desc.

response of 289 contains --> 7 imgs and 2 desc.

response of 232 contains --> 4 imgs and 3 desc.

response of 569 contains --> 0 imgs and 4 desc.

response of 962 contains --> 9 imgs and 0 desc.

Comment: Not sure to understand why this approach would not generalize well. Anyway, I answered using the requirements and data you posted, perhaps you should revise your question to better explain your actual use case. Cheers.